# AWS :The following resource(s) failed to create: [KMSKey, MountTarget2, MountTarget, lambdaStack, dbStack]

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, whatsapp

I was trying to create a AWS stack to deploy  Whatsapp Business client API. But Creating stack throws following error.
error: The following resource(s) failed to create: [KMSKey, MountTarget2, MountTarget, lambdaStack, dbStack]

I followed this documentation steps.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/get-started/installation/aws

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Probably it was a network connection issue